# Google APP script to convert value into TRUE for setting MultipleChoice answer key

Tags: google-apps-script

I’ve searched a script that automates google form from my question banks (g-sheets).
All of my questions are multiple choice.  I already added the **setPoints()** and **setRequired()**, however, for the answer key, I can’t find a way on how to script the value of my Answer’s column into **TRUE** when it meets the criteria.  Below are the codes:

```
function getSpreadsheetData(sheetName) {
// This function gives you an array of objects modeling a worksheet's tabular data, where the first items — column headers — become the property names.
var arrayOfArrays = SpreadsheetApp.openById("GoogleSheetID").getSheetByName(sheetName || 'question').getDataRange().getValues();
console.log("Spreadsheet: " + arrayOfArrays[0]);
console.log("Spreadsheet: " + arrayOfArrays[1]);
var headers = arrayOfArrays.shift();
return arrayOfArrays.map(function (row) {
return row.reduce(function (memo, value, index) {
if (value) {
memo[headers[index]] = value;
}
return memo;
    }, {});
  });
}

function onOpen(e){

var form = FormApp.openById("GoogleFormID");

form.setTitle('DO ANY TITLE YOU WANT HERE');
form.setDescription('This is an example of Form generation');
getSpreadsheetData().forEach(function (row) {
var capitalizedName = row.Number.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + row.Number.slice(1);
console.log("Spreadsheet: " + capitalizedName);

form.addPageBreakItem()
   .setTitle(capitalizedName);
    var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle(row.Questions)
    .setPoints(1)
    .setRequired(true)
    .setChoices([
      item.createChoice(row.Option1),
      item.createChoice(row.Option2),
      item.createChoice(row.Option3),
      item.createChoice(row.Option4)

    ]);

  });
}

function onSubmit(e) {
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var items = form.getItems();
  while(items.length > 0){
    form.deleteItem(items.pop());
  }

}
```

I’ve also search that to make choices the right answer, you just put TRUE or something like this:

```
item.createChoice(row.Option1, true),
item.createChoice(row.Option2, false),
item.createChoice(row.Option3, false),
item.createChoice(row.Option4, false)
```

However, this will only set Option1 as always the right answer.  I want that **TRUE** or **FALSE** will be automatically place when found the right answer as stated in column G of my google sheets. Attach is my sheet:
[GoogleSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swII9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me a while and I experience a weird issue, which is: **After the Questions are set and the form saved, refreshing the page or trying to answer deletes all the options from one of the options (not always the same option)**. 
I still have no clue why does this happen and I will investigate it later, but my code can give you an idea.

I changed your code a bit and added a new function which returns true or false for each option depending on the value of the G column:

```
    form.addPageBreakItem()
    .setTitle(capitalizedName);
    var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle(row.Questions)
    .setPoints(1)
    .setRequired(true)
    .setChoices([
      item.createChoice(row.Option1, checktrue(row, row.Option1)),
      item.createChoice(row.Option2, checktrue(row, row.Option2)),
      item.createChoice(row.Option3, checktrue(row, row.Option3)),
      item.createChoice(row.Option4, checktrue(row, row.Option4))

    ]);

  });

}

function checktrue(row, option){
  var numRow = 2;
  var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var colA = sprsheet.getRange("A2:A5").getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < colA.length; i++){
    if (colA[i] == row.Number){

      numRow += i;

    }
  }   

  var answer = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("G"+numRow).getValue();

  if (option == answer){

    return true

  } else {

    return false
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for the reply..  there is TypeError: Cannot call method "getActiveSheet" of null ---> at this point `var sprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`

Comment: I've got what i need..  do I Edit my question to include the added script or "Answer my Question" ?..  sorry i'm newbies in stack...

Comment: Ah, it returns null if there is no Spreadsheet attached. In your case I guess you used `openById` or similar. There is no need to change your post, accepting the correct answer is enough :)